# How to add Alamofire in Xcode 10.1

Tags: ios, cocoapods, alamofire

I am getting following error when i compile the application after adding the Alamofire using the CocaPods.

```
error: SWIFT_VERSION '5.0' is unsupported, supported versions are: 3.0, 4.0, 4.2. (in target 'Alamofire')
```

Podfile: `pod 'Alamofire', '~> 5.0.0-beta.5'`

I am following [link](https://cocoapods.org/pods/Alamofire) to add Alamofire in my `Swift 5` project

```
Xcode Version: 10.1
```

Comment: Isn't Swift 5 starting from XCode 10.2? So why should it work?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`Swift 5` support for `Xcode` was added in `version 10.2`. To use `Alamofire` with `Swift 5` you will need to update your `Xcode` version. Other suggestion is to downgrade your `Alamofire` version to `4.8.2` or change `Swift` version to `4.2` in pod settings.

---

Good luck :)

Answer (score 2):

`Swift 5` version support in `XCode 10.2`. You can not use the beta version of **Alamofire** in `XCode 10.1`. To use **Alamofire** in **XCode 10.1** version you can simply use this

```
pod 'Alamofire'
```

instead of

```
pod 'Alamofire', '~> 5.0.0-beta.5'
```

Hope this will help.

Answer (score 2):

Update Xcode to 10.2 or download the latest Xcode, which support Swift 5.0. Its better to keep updated rather than using latest version of any library to an old Xcode version. From Xcode 10.2 it support Swift 5